# I can't close Fancybox using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a problem closing a Fancybox using selenium Webdriver. On the fancy-box is a big "X" located for closing it:

[image]

This is the source code of the "X" closing Element:

```html
<a href="javascript:;" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" title="Close"></a>
```

I tried this but without success:

```java
driver.findElement(By.className("fancybox-item fancybox-close")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/a")).click();
```

PS: please see snapshot

Comment: this is the source code of the "X" closing Element:<a class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;" title="Close"/>

Answer (score 1):

We use fancybox on our site, and it is usually inside of an iFrame (at least with our implementation).

In order to find and interact with elements inside an iFrame, you have to switch your driver to the frame first.  Here's a simple implementation in c#.

```
var iframe = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("youriframeselector");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);
//find and click the x...
Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is for duplicate elements on the page.

Debug your code and ensure that:

```java
driver.findElements(By.className("fancybox-item fancybox-close")).size()
```

evaluates to 1

Often times, if Selenium doesn't complain when you do a `.click()` but the action you expect doesn't happen, you'll find that there is more than one element matching your `Find.By` and WD has clicked the wrong one. If you find that it evaluates to >1, you'll need to write a more specific selector

Answer (score 0):

Your `className` selector isn't working, because those are two different class names - you can't use both at once. Try either of these selectors to see if they find the X correctly:

```java
driver.findElement(By.className("fancybox-item")).click();
```

or

```java
driver.findElement(By.className("fancybox-close")).click();
```

But remember to double-check that there aren't any other elements on the screen with the same class, otherwise the selector won't work.